Topic authorization failed for plain listeners after upgrading strimzi kafka cluster from 0.36.1 to 0.40.0
After upgrading strimzi kafka cluster from 0.36.1 to 0.40.0. plain listeners not able to connect to kafka from port 9092. it throws
in consumers, producers:
"Can't connect Not authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed]"
in Kafka brokers:
INFO Principal = User:ANONYMOUS is Denied Operation = Describe from host = xx.xx.xx.xx on resource = Topic:LITERAL:topic-name
but with tls via 9094 port it allows to connect both producers and consumers to cluster. below is my listener config
listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: nodeport
        tls: false      
      - name: tlsnp
        port: 9094
        type: nodeport
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
authorization:
      type: simple
      superUsers:
        - CN=xxx-user


The user is ANONYMOUS. So that will be a user connecting through the 9092 listener where you don't have any authentication configured. That would likely be also why it is denied the operation because even if you have some ALC configured for some user, you likely don't have them for the ANONYMOUS user. This also doesn't seem like anything to do with Strimzi upgrade, just with the client and where it connects.

I am using strimzi-registry-operator. ther author has provided a sample for authorization and plain together(https://github.com/lsst-sqre/strimzi-registry-operator/blob/main/minikube/kafka.yaml). it was working until upgrading strimzi version to 0.40.0
